# AWS CloudFront will only invalidate entire cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to invalidate the CloudFront cache entry for a specific path, say `/api/dict/bob/article/1`, but it has no effect. I've experimented with different wildcards, for instance:

- `/*/1`
- `/api/dict/bob/article/*`
- `/api/dict/bob/*`
- `/api/dict/*`

But in the end, the only invalidation that actually removes the object from the cache is the catch-all `/*`

The path's origin is custom (API Gateway)

Cache policy:
Minimum TTL: 60,
Maximum TTL:28800,
Default TTL: 10800

Cache key:

- query-strings all
- cookies: all
- headers: whitelist (one param)

Update: I managed to invalidate an svg-file from an s3 origin. The api origin requires an `x-api-key` http-header. Could that make a difference?

Comment: Is the client caching data as well? Cache invalidations can take a few seconds, but aside from that, I never had any problems.

Comment: I get responses from CloudFront with header `x-cache: Hit from cloudfront` so it's not locally cached. And invalidation for `/*` works immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think * can be only in the end. Are you sure it is not a client caching and you waited for the invalidation to finish? It is a slow process, not instant for sure. You can track its progress either on the UI or using the CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

> To invalidate files, you can specify either the path for individual
> files or a path that ends with the * wildcard, which might apply to
> one file or to many, as shown in the following examples:
>
> /images/image1.jpg

> /images/image*

> /images/*

Comment: Yes, I'm positive it's not client caching. I even try different browsers + curl, and I check response headers. Invalidation works for `/*`, but nothing more specific than that.

Comment: Can you open a support ticket? This looks  like a bug.

Comment: If that is the case, it's a major bug, especially when considering that you have to pay for each invalidation. I'll report it to Amazon and  update this question if I get something useful from it.